# Drag & drop files from remote location to windows explorer

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop

I have a hard time dragging and dropping files from a remote location to windows explorer. I use a swing ui that displays the contents of the server. Now I have implemented a TransferHandler and a Transferable to bring the files to windows explorer.

The problem here is: Windows explorer, or almost any drag operation, calls the method Transferable.getTransferData over and over again, not just when the mouse button is released over the drag target. This is problematic for me because getTransferData fetches the files from the server (which takes quite some time).

IMHO I need some sort of lazy file but I am unsure how the drag handling on windows is implemented. I want to fetch the files only if the mouse button is released over a valid drop target for the files in the native system.

Does anybody know how this can be achieved?

Comment: The `DragSourceListener` will be [notified](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/dnd/DragSourceListener.html#dragDropEnd(java.awt.dnd.DragSourceDropEvent)) when the DnD ends but I don’t know whether this helps building a lazy transfer. It’s a pity that the AWT data transfer does not provide it by itself.

Comment: Why does it take so much time ? You just need to provide a `List` of `File`s which does not require to download them. I would assume you already have those `File` instances available in your Swing UI

Comment: @Robin: The files are on the server! And how should I get them without downloading them, so that they appear in the desired place? BTW: This is a proprietary protocol with authentication, so URIs won't help.

Comment: To create a `File` instance, you do not need to download them. Not sure however whether that is possible with the proprietary protocol with authentication.

Comment: Robin, please, of what use are empty File instances when the content cannot be read?